# Regarding changes in the accepted manuscript

Tags: publications, errors-erratum

My paper got accepted before 13 days back in AEU journal. But I want to make several changes (only word change) to the accepted manuscript. How do I request the editor to send my corrected manuscript. Will they allow several changes in the accepted manuscript.

Changes are not in the result, tables, graphs.
Changes means reedit some words...

Need help urgently.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Can you please add a little clarification to your post?  Is this a journal publication or a conference publication?

Comment: Have you asked the editor?  They can give you a definitive answer, while we don't know the details of your situation.  (But, as a general rule, you can make changes like this.)

Answer (score 8):

Typically, journals will send you page proofs after your manuscript is accepted and before it's published.  A limited number of changes for clarity is usually fine at that stage (especially if it would have to be printed as errata later).

If the journal is not intending to generate page proofs (e.g. it's a rapid electronic publication format), or if there are more than a handful of changes (six or so), or if they are large enough so they might change the layout of the whole paper, simply contact the editor as soon as possible explaining exactly what you wish to change and why.  Assuming all the changes are minor and make the paper better, the answer is usually that it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

You ought to make the changes before the accepted manuscript is published. Do check with the regulation of your journal which might include page restrictions before doing so.

In your request to the editor, it would be wiser to include both old and new versions to the editor (clearly stating which is which) and a separate file indicating where the changes have been made and what they are (like in [CSE](http://www.councilscienceeditors.org/wp-content/uploads/v23n3p103.pdf) or [APS](http://www.apsstylemanual.org/formattingAPSJournalArticles/corrigendum.htm)).

If your request is not accepted, then your last option would be to include the changes as corrigendum in the journal site if facilitated, otherwise at your own website.